# JUnit Boolean test appears incorrect

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Just writing a simple JUnit test on a simple method and think there is some sort of issue tho i may be overlooking something in plain sight. So I have this class right here and in the JUnit test I am just testing the method @ the bottom.

```
public class BudgetRecordItem {
    private boolean rowChangeFlag;  

    public boolean isRowChangeFlag() {
        return rowChangeFlag;
    }
    public void setRowChangeFlag(boolean rowChangeFlag) {
        this.rowChangeFlag = rowChangeFlag;
    }

    public void rowChangeFlag(boolean rowChange){
        if(rowChange){
            this.setRowChangeFlag(true);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the JUnit test class

```
public class BudgetRecordItemTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testRowChangeFlag(){
        BudgetRecordItem bri = new BudgetRecordItem();
        bri.rowChangeFlag(false);
        assertEquals(null,bri.isRowChangeFlag());
    }

}
```

I would think (from my understanding) that since I never inititalize the Boolean value `rowChangeFlag` to false then if I call the method in the JUnit test with a value of false according to the method in the main class It should only set the rowChangeFlag when it is true. So since I never Initialzed it to false It should not have a value of fasle.

But if I change the value of null in the test call the Test passes meaning that it actually is returning a false value

any ideas or am i Just brain farting?

Comment: primitive `boolean` defaults to false not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing `boolean` primitives with `Boolean` Objects. `primitives` like `boolean` cannot be null and `boolean` is auto-initialized to `false`.

Comment: Yeah @gtgaxiola pointed that out too. Thanks tho, should have known that!